# Gradle Sonar Build Issue

Tags: gradle, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, jenkins-agent

I am using Jenkins slave for building by nodejs lambda. My gradle version is 4.4.1 and I am using sonar plug in 2.4. Sonar build is failing in jenkins slave. Below is the stacktrace

```
    23:51:16.059 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    23:51:16.060 [ERROR]    
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build 
    failed with an exception.
    23:51:16.060 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    23:51:16.060 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
    23:51:16.060 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed 
    for task ':sonarqube'.
    23:51:16.060 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unable to execute 
    SonarQube....
    ...................
    23:51:16.063 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to bootstrap from server. 
    Bootstrap index was:
    23:51:16.063 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    sonar-deprecated-4.3.2.jar,sonar-graph-4.3.2.jar,hibernate-entitymanager-
    3.4.0.GA.jar,xstream-1.3.1.jar,xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar,sonar-channel-
    4.1.jar,maven-plugin-registry-2.2.0.jar,maven-model-2.2.0.jar,maven-
    profile-2.2.0.jar,sonar-colorizer-4.3.2.jar,sonar-check-api-
    4.3.2.jar,plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar,commons-codec-1.8.jar,sonar-plugin-api-
    4.3.2.jar,ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar,picocontainer-2.14.3.jar,commons-
    beanutils-1.8.3.jar,commons-dbutils-1.5.jar,logback-core-
    1.0.13.jar,geronimo-spec-jta-1.0-M1.jar,sonar-java-api-4.3.2.jar,maven-
    artifact-2.2.0.jar,hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar,h2-
    1.3.172.jar,woodstox-core-lgpl-4.0.4.jar,sonar-update-center-common-
    1.8.jar,akiban-persistit-3.2.7.jar,sonar-home-4.3.2.jar,hibernate-
    annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar,javassist-3.4.GA.jar,sonar-markdown-
    4.3.2.jar,log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar,commons-lang-2.6.jar,slf4j-api-
    1.7.5.jar,maven-settings-2.2.0.jar,blueprints-core-2.2.0.jar,commons-pool-
    1.5.4.jar,stax2-api-3.0.1.jar,gson-2.2.4.jar,commons-dbcp-1.4.jar,sonar-
    batch-4.3.2.jar,guava-10.0.1.jar,plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar,maven-project-
    2.2.0.jar,hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar,sonar-duplications-4.3.2.jar,antlr-
    2.7.6.jar,mybatis-3.2.2.jar,staxmate-2.0.0.jar,jcl-over-slf4j-
    1.7.5.jar,json-simple-1.1.1.jar,sonar-core-4.3.2.jar,sonar-batch-maven-
    compat-4.3.2.jar,sonar-squid-4.1.jar,commons-io-2.4.jar,commons-
    configuration-1.6.jar,dom4j-1.6.1.jar,commons-collections-3.2.1.jar,logback-
    classic-1.0.13.jar,jcommon-1.0.12.jar
    23:51:16.063 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at
   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.getScannerEngineFiles(Jars.java:88)
    23:51:16.063 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at 
    org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
    23:51:16.063 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at 
 org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
    23:51:16.063 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    at 
  
 org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLaun
    cherFactory.java:75)
    23:51:16.063 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   
    ... 48 more
    23:51:16.063 [ERROR] 
    [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Any pointers to find the root cause will be of great help

I am also using jacoco plug in version 0.7.1.201405082137

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube server 4.3.2 is very old now. The scanner you are using is probably no more compatible. Please consider updating all you SonarQube stack (server, scanner, plugins, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the versions of the SonarQube plugin (sonarqube) and other related plugins (such as JaCoCo) are compatible with your Gradle version (4.4.1). You might want to check the plugin documentation or release notes for compatibility information.